# Math using property value in LESS

Tags: css, less

Is it possible to do this using LESS?

```
.something {
    margin: 10px;
    width: (500px - @margin-left - @margin-right);
    /* Calculates as: 500px - 10px - 10px = 480px */
}
```

So that LESS would calculate the `width` attribute based on the previously-set values of the `margin` attribute. So if I was to change the margin or base-width, the width would auto-calculate.

**Result**

```
.something {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 480px;
}
```

Comment: No; use variables.

Comment: Waaah. Okay, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You might try

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

but that only works with padding. It will then substract the padding off of the width like you've tried in your example. But then again, it only works with padding